# Packet filtering with scapy

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy

How can I filter packets from a certain IP and subnet? This is what I've got so far:

```
from scapy.all import *

def print_packet(pkt):
    print pkt.summary()

pkt=sniff(filter = 'tcp and host = <source IP address>', prn=print_packet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to match a subnet using `CIDR` notation:

```
filter = "tcp and src='192.168.2.0/24'"
```